# ClassNotFound With Maven WAR file

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-dependency

I looked around for a solution to this but could find anything reasonable. Most of them are related to JARs. I keep getting this frustrating error:

> 15-Jan-2020 11:36:06.605 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)

It comes from commons-logging.jar (1.2).

I have added my dependency, like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The version comes from the parent pom.xml

I have these two plugins of note:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pal-copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
                <excludeClassifiers>shared</excludeClassifiers>
                <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <silent>true</silent>
                <useBaseVersion>false</useBaseVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <addDefaultEntries>true</addDefaultEntries>
                <addBuildEnvironmentEntries>true</addBuildEnvironmentEntries>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <classpathPrefix>WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <classesClassifier>shared</classesClassifier>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\lib</outputDirectory>
        <webResources>
            <webResource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/ProcessOrderService</directory>
                <include>*.*</include>
                <targetPath>/ProcessOrderService/wsdl/</targetPath>
            </webResource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The kicker is, when I put the commons-logging.jar in the Tomcat's lib folder, It works like a charm.

There is a dependency that I have in this war file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-files</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This also uses commons-logging, with the scope `compile`. But this dependency has to remain `provided`. Cant change that!

The only other dependency that might have caused a conflict or something was the activemq-core.jar but I added the exclusions parameter to it. But still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that any dependency that common between `common-files` and a war is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat classloader considers the application local dependencies as last (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

My best guess there is already this library (different version) somewhere in the Tomcat classpath (not surprisingly as it is an Apache logging library).

You can try to define the commons-logging as optional, it wont get transitively imported and will use whats available in Tomcat (assuming that version works fine with your code). Alternatively you need to find the library and replace/upgrade it.

Comment: So you are saying, make `<optional>true</optional>` in both my WAR and `common-files` dependency?

Comment: Use when declaring `common-files` dependency in your POM

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: I will select yours as the answer. It did nudge me in the right direction. Although to get this to work I need to figure out shared.loader stuff under tomcat. The problem is if its "inheriting" from a `provided` dependency, everything is provided. If I find a full solution later on, i will write it down later. Thanks for the help. That loader thing was helpful.